# Canvas resize image object and repeat pattern

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My canvas is 500px x 500px.
I have a png image that is 500px x 500px:
[image: space image]

I want to re-size the image to be say... 100px x 100px, and then use that re-sized image as part of defining a repeat pattern and then using that as a fillStyle to repeat across the whole canvas. This is what I do...

```
//...define canvas, ctx, width and height above

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  _self = this;
  drawBG();
}
image.src = 'img.png';

function drawBG() {
  var space = ctx.createPattern(_self, 'repeat');
  ctx.fillStyle = space;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Now, this is all well and good if I want to waste my own time. See, the space image is the same size as the canvas. My question is... How do you first resize the original image(in javascript) to then later create a pattern with it?

P.S. How do you re-size an image on stack overflow? This image I have showing here is to big for it's purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw your image on a second offscreen canvas, with `drawImage(img, x, y, resizedWidth, resizedHeight)` and then use this canvas as pattern.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  // create an off-screen canvas
  var patt = document.createElement('canvas');
  // set the resized width and height
  patt.width = 50;
  patt.height = 50;
  patt.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0,0, patt.width, patt.height);
  // pass the resized canvas to your createPattern
  drawBG(patt);
}
image.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/500/500';

function drawBG(patternCanvas) {
  var space = ctx.createPattern(patternCanvas, 'repeat');
  ctx.fillStyle = space;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```